# Panda Pivot Column Merge Removal and Flattening

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, tableau-api

Trying to get crosstab data from Tableau API, however, when I pivot the table I get bad column names and can't figure out how to change them:

|  | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Col_1.1 |  |  | Col_2.1 | Col_2.2 | col 2.3 |
| 0 | data | data | data | data | data |
| 1 | more data | more data | more data | more data | more Data |

However, I want the data to look like this

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col_2.1 | Col_2.2 | col 2.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data | data | data |
| more data | more data | more data | more data | more Data |

I have been able to generate table 1 without problems, I just need to try and make it where col3 is not basically a "merge" column when exported to Excel, but instead displays the data as formatted in Table B

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x[0] if (x[0]>x[1]) else x[1])
```

---

[image]